# table display in Jupyter notebook using BeakerX widget

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using **BeakerX** and it's interactive tables which are great.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from beakerx import *
```

I can display my table by from df (type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame):

```
df
```

or

```
display(df)
```

this gives me dynamic table, with all sorting options, export, etc.
However, after sorting on column (it stays pandas.core.frame.DataFrame):

```
df.sort_values('column_name')
```

I can still display tables as above, but all advanced options are not accessible. Only simple sorting works.

Any solutions?

Thanks for your insights.